# ListView items change background color

Tags: android, listview, background, scroll, flicker

I'm having a weird behaviour in my application... A have a ListView, where odd items have `#ffffff` background and even items have `#f2f7f7`, and looks like this:

[image: Activity start OR touching list (without release)]

However, as soon as I start scrolling the list, the even items slightly change color, becoming `#f7f7f7`, like this:

[image: When scrolling and after scroll release]

Any ideas? If you need more info, please ask. I'm baffeld with this behaviour.

**Additional info:**

I'm setting each item's background color in `getView()` method, like this:

```
protected final int[] colors = new int[] { R.drawable.states_list_odd, R.drawable.states_list_even };
...
// Alternates list items' background
int colorPos = position % colors.length;
convertView.setBackgroundResource(colors[colorPos]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple stuff, actually. `android:scrollingCache="false"` solved this issue.

Answer (score 3):

The Views used for the items are being reused when you scroll the list (there's no need to create the new ones). So, when you scroll down the list, the item at position 0 may be rendered at position 10. It will be the same View object, and before showing getView will be called with convertView parameter set to this particular View - so you can fill it with data (and specify your styles). It's just an optimization.

So, you need to specify the background color for the item each time getView is called for it in your list adapter.

Comment: I updated my question, to show how do I set each item's background color at `getView()`.

Answer (score 1):

programmaticly try this. `yourListView.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);`